# Why infinitely many solutions for $a=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The question states

The Initial value problem $y'=2\sqrt{y},y(0)=a$ has

(a) unique solution if $a<0$

(b) no solutions if $a<0$

(c)infintely many solutions for $a=0$

(d)unique solution if $a\geq 0$

It is given option (c) as correct..

My opinion is for $a=0$, clearly will have trival solution $y=0$ and after solving this i.e.

$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}\frac{dy}{dx}&=2\sqrt{y}\\\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y}}&=2dx\\2\sqrt{y}&=2x+c\ \text{integrating both sides}\\\sqrt{y}&=x+C\\y&=(x+C)^2\end{aligned}\end{equation}$

Using the initial condition for $a=0$, $y(0)=0$ gives $c=0$, so we got the solution as $y=x^2$, and the other is the trivial solution so there are only two solutions...

So, why it is concluded as ininitely many solutions for $a=0$....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: [Many duplicates](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24y%27%3D2%5Csqrt%7By%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%3D2*sqrt%28y%29+%2C+y%280%29%3D0) also only finds one solution.

Comment: $y$ can stay equal to $0$ for $x$ close to $0,$ and take off later.

Comment: the solution y=0 for t<t1, than the solution y(t1)=0 gives again two solutions, and you can take any t1, so  c) is right.

Comment: OK , I got it now.

Comment: can you please ellaborate how you got this solution... I am not getting this.. . how $x_0$ come in to the picture.. and why $y=0\ for\ (x<x_0)$